# Lubuntu in PowerPC

Tags: lubuntu, powerpc

How do I get Lubuntu 16.04 to run faster?

(For a friend I installed Lubuntu 16.04 -- supported till April 2021) -- in a on an old iBook G4, which runs on PowerPC.)

Comment: These are two questions. Remove one, otherwise the question will be closed.

Comment: What do you mean by "running slow"? Most likely the comp is low of RAM. You can't do much with that.

Comment: Specs I found online say the installed RAM is 256 MB (with capacity for up to 1.25 GB). It was running until some of the Internet software became out of date an irreplaceable. I assume my friend added RAM; it functioned fine (but funky) under the original OS.

Comment: It is very low RAM for today. It will be slow.

Comment: Have a look at http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/  "*Maintenance updates are provided for 5 years for Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Cloud, Ubuntu Base, and Ubuntu Kylin. All the remaining flavours are supported for 3 years.*"  Lubuntu 16.04 LTS is EOL & unsupported so be aware only parts of your system actually are supported; your GUI/desktop is EOL.

Comment: https://lubuntu.me/test-xenial-6/  "*Lubuntu 16.04 will be supported until April 2019.*"  It's still on-topic on this site, just please be aware you're talking about an OS that officially is EOL & thus consider security implications of using the EOL software.  You won't be able to use Lubuntu support options either.

Comment: This chart https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOL#Ubuntu_16.04_Xenial_Xerus  confirms Lubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached its End of Public Support.

Comment: If I remember correcly the last powerpc version of Lubuntu is 16.04.x and it has passed end of life.

Comment: Is there hope for old trusty Mac Mini G4 working as home server?
I would be happy with a super minimal install and local compilation of packages, any suggestion about the distro?

Answer (score 1):

Lubuntu 16.04 LTS has, indeed, passed its [End of Public Support](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOL#Ubuntu_16.04_Xenial_Xerus), as per its own blog: [Lubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) Released!](http://lubuntu.me/xenial-released)  says "Lubuntu 16.04 LTS will be supported until April 2019, with three years of support."

Therefore, suggest you [follow this procedure](https://lubuntu.me/tag/powerpc/) to upgrade the supported Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with the new LXQt desktop.

And, the classic answer to how to get an OS to run faster is to remove packages, add more RAM, and/or replace the 4200 RPM PATA (aka IDE) drive with a [faster PATA drive](https://www.google.com/search?q=upgrade%20G4%20MacBook%20IDE%20drive) [SSDs do exist](https://www.google.com/search?q=PATA%20SSD%202.5).

Comment: My apologies, got interrupted and when I came back, had a Senior Moment. Fixed.